# accepts_nested_attributes_for with multiple nesting and polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to pass two-levels nested attributes hash while updating model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :messages, as: :discussable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussable, polymorphic: true
end
```

So when I try to pass hash like the following, it simply doesn't say parent model that any of nested models was changed (`changed_for_autosave?` is false because `nested_records_changed_for_autosave?` is false)

```
{steps_attributes: [{id: "1", messages_attributes: [{body: "Some message"}]}]}
```

But it works fine, when some of the fields of Step model changed (other words, one level nesting works fine).

What I did right now is: `@item.steps.each(&:updated_at_will_change!)` in the controller, which is obviously a dirty hack. Is this intended behavior or bug of Rails?

Comment: Are you sure you are whitelisting the nested attributes in your controller? If not please add the relevant controller code?

Comment: Absolutely... actually, I tried it in console with plain hash, so strong_params is not involved.

Comment: I can't reproduce this `i = Item.last`,  `i.assign_attributes({steps_attributes: [{id: i.steps.last.id, messages_attributes: [{body: "Some message"}]` `i.changed_for_autosave?` => true.

Comment: Weird... Maybe something else is involved. I simplified the models for that example. What version of Rails do you use? Mine is 4.2.1

Comment: Rails 4.0.3 (I guess i should update my sample app)  https://github.com/maxcal/sampleapp/tree/30443812

Comment: I'll try to experiment with your repo and write back here later. I guess that may be an issue somewhere else in my models. They are pretty complex and I already had some strange issues with them.

Comment: I can confirm, that it works fine with your repo and Rails 4.2.1. Exploring farther...